# scss file not compiling in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The scss file in not compiling in reactjs even after having the required dev dependencies .I have used create-react-app to create the app.
Here is the package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "mydecisionapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.11",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "style": "^0.0.3",
    "validator": "8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the package style.scss file .

```
$brand-color:blue;
* {
color: $brand-color;
}
```

I looked at all imports in index.js file and it is completely ok but still, I don't see scss compiling .

Answer (score 1):

create-react-app is not configured by default to support scss files. Try reading this [How to add SASS/SCSS to a create-react-app](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/how-to-add-sass-or-scss-to-create-react-app-c303dae4b5bc)

Comment: i installed sass loader and converter ."node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",

Comment: Follow the link I provided in the answer. You have to eject create-react-app default configuration and tune it to support scss file compilation

Comment: I did it using npm and a separate css file with the same name was created.But do I need to run npm watch CSS everytime i make changes to my scss file .I don't see CSS file being autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Pls ensure that your version of react-scripts inside the the package.json file is at least 2.0.0.

This is stated at the top of the documentation that can be found here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

> Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i sass-loader node-sass
```

I was having the same issue, and it worked for me :)